# T-SQL WITH... UPDATE example explanation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I just can't find documentation or explanation how a certain part of the following query works.

Query:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
    SELECT Id, 
           Foo, 
           FIRST_VALUE(Foo) OVER (ORDER BY Id) + 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) - 1 AS newFoo
    FROM mytable
    WHERE Bar= 1 
        AND Id >= 111
)
UPDATE ToUPDATE
SET Foo = newFoo
```

It came from SO user [Giorgos Betsos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2149718/giorgos-betsos) as an answer to another question that is similar to the problem described below.

Lets say we have a Table like this:

```
 Id   Foo  Bar
  2     5    1 
  3     6    1
 13   111   22
111     7    1
122    16    1
154    17    1
176    18    1
```

We want to use a query that will:

- take all rows with `Bar=1` and with `Id >= 111`
- order rows by Id ascending
- update all the `Foo` such that the new value is equal to value of the previous row incremented by 1, starting from row with `Id = 111`

So the resulting Table will look like:

```
 Id   Foo  Bar
  2     5    1 
  3     6    1
 13   111   22  <-- not affected 
111     7    1
122     8    1
154     9    1
176    10    1
```

---

Now, the query works great, even an example was given here: [**EXAMPLE**](http://rextester.com/AQRQN73355)

But I don't understand why the WITH / UPDATE combination works?

Why does the underlying table get updated? At first glance I thought only the view/temporary table returned by the WITH will get updated leaving the underlying table unchanged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you update a column in a CTE, SQL Server will trace that column back to its source table.  In this case, the `mytable` table has a column called `Foo`, so it will actually get updated in the `mytable` table.

By the way, a CTE is not a temporary table of any sort, nor is it even a view.  It is just a convenient way of wrapping SQL code/functionality.  Under the hood, I expect that the CTE will actually compile to a typical `UPDATE` statement, and you can run `EXPLAIN` to convince yourself of this.

You may be left wondering what happens if you try to do an `UPDATE` of a CTE involving a column which can't be traced back to a physical table.  In this case, you will get an error looking something like the following:

> Update or insert of view or function 'cte' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.

The error message says it all.  You tried to update a column which doesn't actually exist in a physical table and SQL Server protested by refusing to do the update.